# Android sending and recieving data

Tags: android, server, user-information-list

I'm making a new app. I want to see user informations. I have taken to user datas but I dont know how can I see that. I have already use Parse server but I couldnt do that with success. Can anybody help me?

Comment: what you tried so far? post your code

Comment: I havent any idea. I have tried just parse but I couldnt do.

Comment: try this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/